# Create editable UITextView inside a UITableViewController cell

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitableview

I created a uitextview inside a uitableviewcontroller programatically but i am unable to edit the textview. Here's an overview to my table layout:

Row1: UILabel

Row2: Uneditable UITextview

Row3: UILabel

Row4: Editable UITextview

Here's what i am doing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
UILabel *label = nil;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(indexPath.row%2==0)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[self.cellBackgroundColor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [label setText:[self.celltitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:[self.cellFontName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] size:[[self.cellFontSize objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]];

    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
}
else{

    UITextView *messageBox= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 150)];
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
       [messageBox setEditable:YES];
[messageBox setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        messageBox.delegate=self;
        messageBox.editable=YES;
    }
     [cell.contentView addSubview: messageBox];


}
return cell;}
```

I have also set textviewdelegate in header file and textviewshouldbeginediting method but row4 textview is still not editable... Any help?

Comment: do the delegate methods respond ?

Comment: No.. delegate methods is not responding..

Comment: Do you have correct linking in your .h and you have added <UITextViewDelegate>?

Comment: Yes i have checked everything is added...

Comment: or other issue could be is you are already setting the seteditable to yes but apparently some view is overlapping your textview. Try setting the different background colors of all of the views and then see where your textview resides on your cell.

Comment: I have reasons to believe this if statement `if(indexPath.row==3)` is not running, it is returning NO for some reason. Could you check if the instructions inside it are running ?

Comment: Have you set the textField shouldBeginediting to NO or YES?

Comment: Actually.. i fixed it.. In interface, the selection field in attributes inspector was set to No selection instead of Single Selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to making the messageBox setEditable and setUserInteractionEnabled, you ALSO have to make sure those properties are enabled in your UITableViewController as well since the UITextView is nested within it!

```
[tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[messageBox setEditable:YES];
[messageBox setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

(*Note, your tableView and TableViewCell both have the same name from this function so I would put that code elsewhere but I added it above just incase)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. May be it will help you..Its working for me

```
 if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
        messageBox.delegate=self;
       [messageBox setEditable:YES];
       [messageBox setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        messageBox.editable=YES;
        [cell addSubview: messageBox];
    }
```

Comment: [cell addSubview: messageBox]; write this line in bracket

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code..Its working for me.. see the changes bellow

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UILabel *label = nil;
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (nil == cell)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if(indexPath.row%2==0)
    {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 50)];
          [label setBackgroundColor:[self.cellBackgroundColor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         [label setText:[self.celltitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:[self.cellFontName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] size:[[self.cellFontSize objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]];

        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
    }
    else{

        UITextView *messageBox= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 100)];

        cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            // Uneditable UITextview
            messageBox.editable=NO;
        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview: messageBox];

    }
}
return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize the cell´s content view before using it. Try this:

```
cell.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, 150)];
```